# Getting a list of all neighbors within a specific distance for every node in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, distance, nodes

I have a small task I would like solve in QGIS. I have a single layer with ~ 30000 nodes. 
How can I create a list for every node in this layer which names all of its neighbors within a specific distance?

The only helpful tutorial I could find was about how to find neighbor polygons in a layer:

http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/find_neighbor_polygons.html

Unfortunately I am just a beginner in python.

How do I adapt the mentioned script for my task?

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

# Replace the values below with values from your layer.
# For example, if your identifier field is called 'XYZ', then change the line
# below to _NAME_FIELD = 'XYZ'
_NAME_FIELD = 'NAME'
# Replace the value below with the field name that you want to sum up.
# For example, if the # field that you want to sum up is called 'VALUES', then
# change the line below to _SUM_FIELD = 'VALUES'
_SUM_FIELD = 'POP_EST'

# Names of the new fields to be added to the layer
_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD = 'NEIGHBORS'
_NEW_SUM_FIELD = 'SUM'

layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Create 2 new fields in the layer that will hold the list of neighbors and sum
# of the chosen field.
layer.startEditing()
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(
        [QgsField(_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD, QVariant.String),
         QgsField(_NEW_SUM_FIELD, QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields()
# Create a dictionary of all features
feature_dict = {f.id(): f for f in layer.getFeatures()}

# Build a spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for f in feature_dict.values():
    index.insertFeature(f)

# Loop through all features and find features that touch each feature
for f in feature_dict.values():
    print 'Working on %s' % f[_NAME_FIELD]
    geom = f.geometry()
    # Find all features that intersect the bounding box of the current feature.
    # We use spatial index to find the features intersecting the bounding box
    # of the current feature. This will narrow down the features that we need
    # to check neighboring features.
    intersecting_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
    # Initalize neighbors list and sum
    neighbors = []
    neighbors_sum = 0
    for intersecting_id in intersecting_ids:
        # Look up the feature from the dictionary
        intersecting_f = feature_dict[intersecting_id]

        # For our purpose we consider a feature as 'neighbor' if it touches or
        # intersects a feature. We use the 'disjoint' predicate to satisfy
        # these conditions. So if a feature is not disjoint, it is a neighbor.
        if (f != intersecting_f and
            not intersecting_f.geometry().disjoint(geom)):
            neighbors.append(intersecting_f[_NAME_FIELD])
            neighbors_sum += intersecting_f[_SUM_FIELD]
    f[_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD] = ','.join(neighbors)
    f[_NEW_SUM_FIELD] = neighbors_sum
    # Update the layer with new attribute values.
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
print 'Processing complete.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with a point layer, the code you attached could be simplified.

You only need to set a proper value for the `_NAME_FIELD` variable and for the *searching distance* (find it within the code).

The following adapted code worked well for me:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

# Replace the values below with values from your layer.
# For example, if your identifier field is called 'XYZ', then change the line
# below to _NAME_FIELD = 'XYZ'
_NAME_FIELD = 'AUTO'

# Names of the new fields to be added to the layer
_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD = 'NEIGHBORS'

layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Create 2 new fields in the layer that will hold the list of neighbors and sum
# of the chosen field.
layer.startEditing()
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(
        [QgsField(_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD, QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()
# Create a dictionary of all features
feature_dict = {f.id(): f for f in layer.getFeatures()}

# Build a spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for f in feature_dict.values():
    index.insertFeature(f)

# Loop through all features and find features that touch each feature
for f in feature_dict.values():
    print 'Working on %s' % f[_NAME_FIELD]
    geom = f.geometry().buffer(600,-1) # The first parameter is the searching distance, set it properly
    # Find all features that intersect the bounding box of the current feature.
    # We use spatial index to find the features intersecting the bounding box
    # of the current feature. This will narrow down the features that we need
    # to check neighboring features.
    intersecting_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
    # Initalize neighbors list and sum
    neighbors = []
    for intersecting_id in intersecting_ids:
        # Look up the feature from the dictionary
        intersecting_f = feature_dict[intersecting_id]
        neighbors.append(intersecting_f[_NAME_FIELD])
        f[_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD] = ','.join(neighbors)
        layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
print 'Processing complete.'
```

If you don't want to include the current node in the final list of nodes, you only need to set an `if` statement, replacing the proper part of the code above with the following code snippet:

```
for intersecting_id in intersecting_ids:
    if intersecting_id != f.id(): # Check if the intersecting id is not the starting node
        # Look up the feature from the dictionary
        intersecting_f = feature_dict[intersecting_id]
        neighbors.append(str(intersecting_f[_NAME_FIELD]))
        f[_NEW_NEIGHBORS_FIELD] = ','.join(neighbors)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! Unfortunately the code lists only the correct neighbors for the one node. The cells of all other nodes are empty.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Numpi I successfully tested it on a sample dataset. Maybe did you set a searching distance value that is too low for reaching the neighboring points?